# How can I use the sortablejs library in CakePHP4?

Tags: javascript, cakephp, es6-modules

I'm trying to use sortablejs with CakePHP4, and I read the ReadMe first.

So, to install it, use `npm install sortablejs --save` To install it, I found something that said to run.

So I went to `cd cake_project/webroot/js` and ran `npm install storablejs --save`.

The two directories `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` are now installed in `webroot/js`.

All of the hierarchies are below.

```
/node_modules
    |
    |- /sortablejs
　　　　　　|- LICENSE
　　　　　　|- package.json
　　　　　　|- /dist
　　　　　　    |- sortable.umd.js
　　　　　　    |- sortable.umd.js.map
　　　　　　|- /modular
　　　　　　    |- sortable.complete.esm.js
　　　　　　    |- sortable.compsle.esm.js.map
　　　　　　    |- sortable.core.esm.js
　　　　　　    |- sortable.esm.js
　　　　　　    |- sortable.esm.js.map
```

I did exactly what the README says.
I put the following in `template/view.php`.

```php
<ul id="items">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>

<?= $this->Html->script('view', ['block' => true]) ?>
```

Next, I added the following to `webroot/js/veiw.js`.

```js
import Sortable from "sortablejs";

let el       = document.getElementById("items");
let sortable = Sortable.create(el);
```

Then I got an error message in the Console of DevTools saying `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use immport statemnt outside a module view.js:1` .

```
import Sortable from 'node_modules/sortablejs';

// ...
```

Check the console log.
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module view.js:1`.
I got the exact same error.

I looked in the `js` directory in the DevTools `Sources` and noticed that sortablejs did not exist.

In the last line of `template/view.php`, add `<? = $this->Html->script('node_modules/sortablejs', ['block' => true]) ? >` in the last line of `template/view.php`.

I called a non-existent file called node_modules.js. So, the `<? = $this->Html->script('node_modules/sortablejs/, ['block' => true]) ? >`. Now `node_modules/sortablejs/.js` is called.

Sorry about that. There's nothing more I can do.
What should I do?
Please help me.

Comment: You have lots of typos and syntax errors in your code. Please make sure that you post the code exactly as you are using it, as otherwise these errors can cloak your actual problem, at least as far as the people here reading this are concerned.

Comment: Can I assume you're not familiar with JavaScript modules (ES6), and your problem is first and foremost that you don't know where to put the files, and how to reference them in the helper? And the usage of the library/examples being another problem?

Comment: Thank you, ndm.

I was astonished to find six tape-mistakes just by my count.
I've fixed them as soon as possible. Thank you very much for pointing this out.

Comment: You are right, ndm. I am not familiar with the JavaScript module (ES6). I also don't understand where to put the file and how to reference it in the helper.

The usage of the library is not really an issue. However, I don't fully understand the `import Sortable from 'sortablejs';` call.

As ndm said, I am not able to reference the library.

Comment: Is it possible to call all files under a directory with `$this->Html->script`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, [**JavaScript modules**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) aren't supported in all browsers, so unless you know that you only target browsers that do support them, you cannot use the `import` syntax, and as the error message states, it would have to be used in a module itself.

As you're not yet familiar with all that stuff, ES6, modules, bundlers, etc, you probably want to go with the UMD library for now, which can be used without any imports or the like.

Assuming the `node_modules` folder would be in your `webroot` folder, the correct path to the UMD library would be the full, root relative URL, eg:

```
/node_modules/sortablejs/dist/sortable.umd.js
```

```php
$this->Html->script('/node_modules/sortablejs/dist/sortable.umd.js', ['block' => true])
```

Then you can directly use the library, just like in [**the examples**](https://sortablejs.github.io/sortablejs/) on the homepage:

```js
new Sortable(swapDemo, {
    swap: true, // Enable swap plugin
    swapClass: 'highlight', // The class applied to the hovered swap item
    animation: 150
});
```

I would suggest to install the modules outside of the webroot folder, and copy or symlink them into your webroot folder afterwards, ideally as part of a build script.

The examples in the GitHub repository are most likely ment for use in context with bundlers like [**Webpack**](https://webpack.js.org/) that would resolve the imports. Using the modules in the browser would look a little bit different, something like this:

```html
<script type="module">
    import Sortable from '/node_modules/sortablejs/modular/sortable.complete.esm.js';
    
    const el = document.getElementById('items');
    const sortable = Sortable.create(el, {
        swap: true, // Enable swap plugin
        swapClass: 'highlight', // The class applied to the hovered swap item
        animation: 150
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, npm! Thank you so much. I was very impressed with your very clear explanation.
Since there are still some parts that I completely understand (`... in context with bundlers like Webpack... `), I will read it again carefully. Thank you very much.